# masm x86 Assembly is it possible to create a pointer to a procedure?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

Is it possible to create a pointer to a procedure in assembly, like how you would create a pointer to a function in C?

`void(*MyFuncPointer)(int a, int b);`

I am assuming that it IS possible, I just do not know how to do it.

Comment: You just use the label (name) of the function and store it wherever you want. `masm` might require the `offset` keyword, same as for any normal variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the address of the a procedure, or anything you can use load effective address instruction.

```
lea eax, CrazyProcedure
mov ebx, eax

CrazyProcedure:
    pop eax
    pop ebx
    add eax, ebx
    ret
```

Comment: You could also just use `mov eax, offset CrazyProcedure`.